# Typescript. How to create generic helper function for following type?

Tags: typescript, generics, literals

Sorry for unclear title but I have no clue on how to describe my question shortly.

I have some type with one literal value and object with flat structure of this types as values (simplified version):

```typescript
type SomeType<T = string> = { value: T };

type SomeTypeMapped = Record<string, SomeType>;
```

I want to write helper (generic) to tell TS that

```typescript
const a = helper({
   A: { value: 'literal-1' },
   B: { value: 'literal-2' }
})
```

has a type of:

```typescript
const a: {
   A: SomeType<"literal-1">;
   B: SomeType<"literal-2">;
}
```

So far the closest solution I found is

```typescript
function helper<V extends string, K extends string>(val: { [key in K]: SomeType<V> }) {
  return val;
}

const a = helper({
  A: { value: 'asd' }.
  B: { value: 'qwe' }
});

// -->

const a: {
    A: SomeType<"asd" | "qwe">;
    B: SomeType<"asd" | "qwe">;
}
```

If I try to modify helper as so:

```typescript
function helper<
  V extends string,
  K extends string,
  T extends { [key in K]: SomeType<V> }
>(val: T) {
  return val;
}
```

it converts the whole map to constant literal type:

```typescript
const a: {
    A: {
        value: "asd";
    };
    B: {
        value: "qwe";
    };
}
```

which is also close to what I'm trying to achieve, but my second point is readability, as

```typescript
const a: {
    A: SomeType<"asd">;
    B: SomeType<"qwe">;
}
```

is much more readable for more complicated examples (with more fields than single 'value').

Can I somehow tell TS that field `A` has exactly type of `SomeType<"asd">` as well as field `B` has type of `SomeType<"qwe">`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Ndovvw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, totally! Thank you! Please post it as an answer explaining what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd write `helper()`:

```
const helper = 
  <T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(val: { [K in keyof T]: SomeType<T[K]> }) => val;
```

The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` is a mapping from the keys of `val` to the associated `string` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) you want to pass into `SomeType`.  So the intent is that when you call

```
const a = helper({
    A: { value: 'literal-1' },
    B: { value: 'literal-2' }
})
```

`T` will be inferred as `{ A: "literal-1"; B: "literal-2" }`.  Then `val` is not of type `T` directly, but of the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[K in keyof T]: SomeType<T[K]>}`.

Note that the compiler is indeed able to infer the type `T` from a value of a *homomorphic mapped type* of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...T[K]...}`.  It's not really well-documented in the current version of the TS Handbook, but there is a section of the now-deprecated v1 of the Handbook about [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) that describes this.

Anyway, that means when you call `helper()` above, `T` is inferred properly, and `val` is inferred to be of this type:

```
/* const a: {
    A: SomeType<"literal-1">;
    B: SomeType<"literal-2">;
} */
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMqBeKBnYAJwEsA7AcwD4coBvKANwEMAbAVwgC4osBfAbgBQggMZxSBKAAsILSIRqYoEAB7AIpACZ4oAJQhjCm9AGsIIOADMeAGnxEyVSgApmLbvQDaAaShkoZhbWyAC63PBIqJCYPiHUvACUONRuQqLikkw0MnIQhM60glDFUACCHoysHNwA5CzE6oSsALQAjDVQvDZFJQBCFW7VUHUNeS0ATB28gomCAPQAVNKy8uj05VAARPWNLa2b-FD9WztjLM3jB50uAHR3SQtzwotQYhLAUEwePcUbEShodDbUZNc77ShCEpHcKIAHRYG7c6XCEzKCPIA)